# Static Bootstrap Website Failed To Build In Jekyll When Publishing to GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, github-pages

I built a website in Bootstrap 5 which is failing to build in Jekyll and publish correctly to Github Pages.
Github Repo: https://github.com/zrentala/Coding-Portfolio-Website

It is giving me this error below, which I have no idea where the problem is and how to fix it. Can someone explain what is going on and how to fix it?

Here is the primary error: **Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs**

Here is the full message:

```
Run actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
/usr/bin/docker run --name ghcrioactionsjekyllbuildpagesv108_75fe66 --label ef7d85 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_SOURCE" -e "INPUT_DESTINATION" -e "INPUT_FUTURE" -e "INPUT_BUILD_REVISION" -e "INPUT_VERBOSE" -e "INPUT_TOKEN" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/Coding-Portfolio-Website/Coding-Portfolio-Website":"/github/workspace" ghcr.io/actions/jekyll-build-pages:v1.0.8
Configuration file: none
  Logging at level: debug
      GitHub Pages: github-pages v228
      GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.3
             Theme: jekyll-theme-primer
      Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0
         Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
 ** Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
                    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs**
         Requiring: jekyll-seo-tag
/usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:86:in `chdir': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs (Errno::ENOENT)
         Requiring: jekyll-coffeescript
         Requiring: jekyll-commonmark-ghpages
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:86:in `sass_load_paths'
         Requiring: jekyll-gist
         Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:114:in `sass_configs'
         Requiring: jekyll-paginate
         Requiring: jekyll-relative-links
         Requiring: jekyll-optional-front-matter
         Requiring: jekyll-readme-index
         Requiring: jekyll-default-layout
         Requiring: jekyll-titles-from-headings
   GitHub Metadata: Initializing...
            Source: /github/workspace/./docs
       Destination: /github/workspace/./docs/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
        Generating: JekyllOptionalFrontMatter::Generator finished in 1.15e-05 seconds.
        Generating: JekyllReadmeIndex::Generator finished in 7.201e-06 seconds.
        Generating: Jekyll::Paginate::Pagination finished in 3.901e-06 seconds.
        Generating: JekyllRelativeLinks::Generator finished in 2.9902e-05 seconds.
        Generating: JekyllDefaultLayout::Generator finished in 1.1501e-05 seconds.
        Generating: JekyllTitlesFromHeadings::Generator finished in 7.5e-06 seconds.
         Rendering: assets/css/style.scss
  Pre-Render Hooks: assets/css/style.scss
  Rendering Markup: assets/css/style.scss
github-pages 228 | Error:  No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-sass-converter-1.5.2/lib/jekyll/converters/scss.rb:119:in `convert'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:101:in `block in convert'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:99:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:99:in `reduce'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:99:in `convert'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:83:in `render_document'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:62:in `run'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:479:in `render_regenerated'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:472:in `block in render_pages'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:471:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:471:in `render_pages'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:192:in `render'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:71:in `process'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-3.9.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-228/bin/github-pages:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/github-pages-228/bin/github-pages:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/github-pages:23:in `<main>'
```

I have tried importing Bootstrap by a different method and changing the source of the Page, neither of which helped.

Comment: Tell GitHub that it shouldn't try to process the site as a Jekyll site by creating an empty `.nojekyll` file in the top-level directory (see [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#static-site-generators)).